# How do I modify this code so the 'add to cart' button actually adds the product to cart? (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am using a 'modal' product integration on my Shopify store, which opens with variations on click of a button. Below is the code for the 'modal' along with the button code. Currently, when the button is clicked, the page refreshes and navigates to the cart, with the product added but variations not.

How can I modify the code to add the name and number inputs to the cart as well?

```
{% comment %}
product-modal.liquid
{% endcomment %}


<div id="product-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Select Options</h2>
    <div class="options">
      {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
        <div class="option">
          <label>{{ option.name }}</label>
          {% for value in option.values %}
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="{{ option.name }}" value="{{ value }}">
              {{ value }}
            </label>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="option">
        <label for="name-input">Name (Max 10 characters)</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-input" maxlength="10">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="number-input">Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="number-input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="submit" id="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button> -->

    <form action="/cart/add" method="post" id="product-form-{{ product.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}">
<div>
<button type="submit" id="add-to-cart" name="add">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</form>
    
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  document.getElementById("add-to-cart").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get the selected options
    var options = [];
    var optionElements = document.querySelectorAll('.options .option input[type="radio"]:checked');
    optionElements.forEach(function(optionElement) {
      options.push({
        name: optionElement.name,
        value: optionElement.value
      });
    });

    // Get the input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name-input");
    var numberInput = document.getElementById("number-input");
    var name = nameInput.value;
    var number = numberInput.value;

    // Perform the add to cart action
    addToCart(options, name, number);
  });

  function addToCart(options, name, number) {
    // Use the Shopify AJAX API to add the product to the cart
    var formData = {
      items: [
        {
          id: {{ "7311393030327" }},
          quantity: 1,
          properties: {
            options: options,
            name: name,
            number: number
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    Shopify.post('/cart/add.js', formData)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Redirect to the cart page
        window.location.href = '/cart';
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error adding product to cart:', error);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: By "the page refreshes" do you specifically mean that `window.location.href = "/cart";` is invoked?  If so, what happens when you debug the AJAX POST request before it?  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when that request is made does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  If the request/response look good, what is `/cart/add.js` and have you debugged it server-side?

Comment: Hey - thanks for the response.
Page refresh - ie it goes straight to cart, but not with the product added.

For reference, when the native 'add to cart' button is clicked (not the modal) the product does actually add to the cart...

Comment: *"it goes straight to cart"* - Now is the time to do some debugging to find more specific information.  You can use your browser's script debugger to place breakpoints in this JavaScript code and observe the specific behavior, confirming if this redirect is specifically the result of the explicit redirect in the code shown or something else.  Additionally, you can observe and debug this AJAX POST operation to see what's happening there.  If you're indicating that this AJAX POST operation is successfully happening then it sounds like the problem is in whatever `/cart/add.js` is *server-side*.

Comment: I've added a comment - the code adds the product to the cart but doesn't add the variations.